# android setrequestorientation lock with current orientation calls on create in some devices

Tags: android, locking, orientation, screen-orientation, device-orientation

Hi and thanks in advance,

I am having a weird issue with screen lock orientation. The funny thing is this problem just happen to me in ONE device, a Samsung galaxy Tab. In the others tablets and smartphones does not react like this.

The thing is, imagine that you detect your orientation and lock it with this code:

```
public void lockScreenOrientation() {
    System.out.println("A VER Q DEVUELVE ESTO: "+((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay().getRotation());
    switch (((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE))
        .getDefaultDisplay().getRotation()) {
    case Surface.ROTATION_90: 
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE); 
        break;
    case Surface.ROTATION_180: 
        setRequestedOrientation(9/* reversePortait */); 
        break;
    case Surface.ROTATION_270: 
        setRequestedOrientation(8/* reverseLandscape */); 
        break;
    default : 
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT); 
    }
}
```

Suppostly, i just want to tell the device to keep the current orientation, but in that tablet it calls the onCreate !! why is that? why only that device? In the others works fine

And i do not want to override onConfigurationChanged because i need to call the code in on create, where the lock code is it....so it gets in a infinite loop........

Can i solve this? or it is a problem or issue of only this device?

best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. It seems the orientation codes are not the same for tablet than to smartphone, i didn't know that.

The problem is that in the tablet the orientation i was trying to set, was wrong for him !! Like it is not the same for the smartphone than to the tablet

I found this other code, that perfectly did the trick for all devices :)

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
//Con esto pilla pantalla completa
screenheight = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
screenwidth = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();

public void lockScreenOrientation() {
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    int rotation = display.getRotation();

    Point size = new Point();
    //display.getSize(size);
    size.x=screenwidth;
    size.y=screenheight;

    int lock = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;

    if (rotation == Surface.ROTATION_0
            || rotation == Surface.ROTATION_180) {
        // if rotation is 0 or 180 and width is greater than height, we have
        // a tablet
        if (size.x > size.y) {
            if (rotation == Surface.ROTATION_0) {
                lock = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
            } else {
                lock = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE;
            }
        } else {
            // we have a phone
            if (rotation == Surface.ROTATION_0) {
                lock = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
            } else {
                lock = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT;
            }
        }
    } else {
        // if rotation is 90 or 270 and width is greater than height, we
        // have a phone
        if (size.x > size.y) {
            if (rotation == Surface.ROTATION_90) {
                lock = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
            } else {
                lock = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE;
            }
        } else {
            // we have a tablet
            if (rotation == Surface.ROTATION_90) {
                lock = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT;
            } else {
                lock = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
            }
        }
    }
    setRequestedOrientation(lock);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

When orientation is changed the OS destroys the activity and rebuilds it.. that is why onCreate is called.  You could just set the activity in your manifest to only allow one orientation:

```
<activity
            android:name=".YourActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
```

Comment: No, but i do not want this. I want to keep the current orientation (it can be portrait landscape or reverses), just for a little way, later i put the sensor on again.
And also, the thing it is that the orientation is NOT changing, i am detecting the current and trying to lock it. In 7 devices i have here it works well, does not call on create because it is not changing anything.....just in the galaxy tab is doing that.... :(